# How to setup Oracle on Windows not to run as local system user

Tags: oracle

I need my Oracle database (single instance 10GR2) to be able to access certain files on the network. Running the service under the local system account prevents this. I will be using UNC paths so I won't run into any drive mapping issues.

What account should I use? How do I setup such an account?

Any expriences are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Services manager (Start -> Run -> "services.msc")
Select the Oracle services you need to change, right-click, and choose "Properties"
Click the "Log On" tab

You can set it to any account you like there.

Comment: Thanks, what I would like to know is if there are any properties this uaccount must have. What pitfalls are there? Password expire etc.

Comment: Those are more serverfault questions as they are administrative in nature, no?

Comment: As long as the account you assign it to has permission to access the network shares you need, I can't think of anything special that would apply which isn't just common sense (like you already pointed out password expiry).